# How to force ansible to use sudo terminal when connecting to remote server

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use sudo terminal when connecting to remote server. Here is the current settings:

```
[localhost]-->key already shared-->[remote server]
```

But when I ssh into remote server, It does not take me directly to bash, it take me to another propitiatory CLI and I have to manually type "shell" on that CLI to login into bash.

```
[localhost]-->key already shared-->[remote server cli]--->[remote server bash]
```

So , following command will take me to CLI not bash, where remote host is 1.2.34

```
localhost> ssh user@1.2.3.4
```

whereas ,following command will open bash directly:

```
localhost> ssh user@1.2.3.4 -t bash
```

question is how to make ansible to by default internally run `-t bash` with it.

Comment: It turned out that its the default behavior of ansible to spawn shell while doing ssh, It can be seen when using `-vvv` option. `-tt 1.2.3.4 '/bin/sh -c`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
chpass -s bash
```

or just

```
chpass
```

to reset the default shell?

Comment: Default shell is always bash, but the server's ssh configuration is spawning CLI when ssh is done to the server from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible will use a non-interactive session, that should read the.bash_profile. Depending on what you want to do, eg. are you trying to execute shell in ansible, this thread may also help,

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29637